# error c2953: class template has already been defined

Tags: c++, templates

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error class template has already been defined. The prof asked us to write a DLinkedOrderedList.template.h, Node.template.h, and Iterator.template.h. We're initially given DLinkedOrderedList.h. The error is only in DLinkedOrderedList.template.h and I'm not sure how to fix it so far:

DLinkedOrderedList.template.h

```
//#include "DLinkedOrderedList.h"

template <class Item, class Order=IsLess>
class DLinkedOrderedList {
public: 

/**
 * Construct an empty list.
 */
DLinkedOrderedList(): m_head(NULL), m_tail(NULL), m_size(0);

/**
 * Make a copy of a list.
 */
DLinkedOrderedList(DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order> const& copy){
    //copy constructor; 
    *m_head = new Node(*copy.m_head); 
    *m_tail = new Node(*copy.m_tail); 

    m_size = copy.m_size; 
};

/**
 * Destruct a list. Delete all dynamically allocated nodes.
 */
~DLinkedOrderedList(){
    Node * here = m_head, * nextNode;

    while ( here != NULL ) {
        nextNode = here->next;
        delete here;
        here = nextNode;
    }   
};

/**
 * Return the current list size. O(1).
 */
unsigned int size() const{
    return m_size; 
};

/**
 * Answer: Is the list empty? O(1).
 */
bool isEmpty() const{
    return (m_size == 0); 
};

/**
 * Get an iterator to the "beginning" or "off the ending" of this list.
 * Default to a forward iterator. Note that the "beginning" of the list for
 * a backward iterator is the tail of the list. Both are O(1).
 */
Iterator begin(Direction direction = FORWARD){return Iterator(m_head); };
Iterator end(Direction direction = FORWARD) {return Iterator(m_tail); }; //or return Iterator(NULL)

/**
 * Insert an item into the correct location in the list according to the
 * ordering defined by our templated Order class. If Order::compare(a, b) is
 * true, then a must come before b in an ordered list. Return a forward
 * iterator pointing to the inserted value. Ordering of duplicate items
 * values does not matter, but each duplicate value should be included
 * exactly in the list. E.g.,
 *
 *     Inserting 2 into list: 1 <--> 2 <--> 3
 *     results in: 1 <--> 2 <--> 2 <--> 3
 *     It doesn't matter which "2 node" is the inserted node.
 *
 * This method should be O(n).
 */
Iterator insert(Item item){
    //Node nodeItem; 
    //Iterator iteratorItem; 

    for (Iterator k = begin(); k != end(); k++){

        if (Order::compare(item, *k )){
            Iterator j = k-1; 
            Iterator l = k+1; 

            Node* here = k.m_ptr; 


        }
    }

};

/**
 * Remove a single "item"-valued item from the list and return true.
 * If no such item is found, return false. O(n).
 */
bool remove(Item item){
    //return true;
};

/**
 * Remove the specific node that "itr" refers to, and return the node's
 * value. "itr" should be adjusted to refer to the item in the "++ position"
 * with respect to the removed node (see comment under Iterator's "kill"
 * method for a detailed description). Note that this may be NULL! O(1).
 *
 * PRECONDITION: Iterator should be pointing at a valid position in the
 * list.
 */
Item remove(Iterator& itr){

};

/**
 * Remove all "item"-valued items from the list and return a count of the
 * number of such items found and removed. O(n).
 */
unsigned int removeAll(Item item){};


};
```

DLinkedOrderedList.h

```
    #pragma once

/**
 * YOU SHOULD NOT MODIFY ANY CODE IN THIS FILE.
 *
 * Comments in this file provide details on how to implement your assignment.
 */

/**
 * StandardFunctors.h provides IsLess, the default Order for a
 * DLinkedOrderedList.
 */
#include "StandardFunctors.h"

/**
 * Direction of traversal for iterators.
 */
enum Direction {FORWARD=1, BACKWARD=2};

/**
 * Class for self-ordering doubley linked list. YOU SHOULD NOT MODIFY ANYTHING
 * "INSIDE" THIS CLASS! Instead, add your own implementations of the class
 * interface to the three files that you will create -- the ones that are
 * included below: DLinkedOrderedList.template.h, Node.template.h, and
 * Iterator.template.h.
 */
template <class Item, class Order=IsLess>
class DLinkedOrderedList {
private:
    /**
     * Private class for list nodes. Node objects are dynamically allocated
     * and freed in the appropriate constructors/operators/methods of the
     * DLinkedOrderedList class.
     */
    class Node {
    public:
        /**
         * Construct a node containing val, with next = _next and prev = _prev.
         */
        Node(Item val = Item(), Node* _next = NULL, Node* _prev = NULL);

        /**
         * Public members giving DLinkedOrderedList and Iterator (see class
         * below) direct access to nodes' data.
         */
        Item  value;
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;

     };

public:
    /**
     * Public iterator class wraps node pointers and supports minimum set.
     * of operators for iterating forward and backward. Iterators store whether
     * or not they are "forward iterators" or "backward iterators".
    * Backward iterators have inverted "operator++" and "operator--" behaviour;
     * i.e., the go to the previous node in the list using "++" and go the next
     * node in the list with "--".
     */
    class Iterator {
    private:
        /**
         * A pointer to the node that this iterator refers to.
         */
        Node* m_node;

        /**
         * A reference to the list that this iterator is "iterating over".
         */
        DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>& m_list;

        /**
         * Defines "forward" or "backward" traversal iterator (see defnition of
         * type Direction at the top of this file).
         */
        Direction m_direction;

        /**
         * INVARIANT: m_node is EITHER an element of lst OR NULL.
         */

    public:
        /**
         * Construct an Iterator from a pointer to a Node, a reference to the
         * list, and a direction. Default to a forward iterator.
         *
         * PRECONDTION: ptr is EITHER an element of list OR NULL.
         */
        Iterator(
            Node* const node,
            DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>& list,
            Direction direction = FORWARD);

    /**
     * Increment an iterator; i.e., go to the "next node" according to
     * the value of m_direction. I.e.,  "++" operator on forward
     * iterators follows the NEXT pointer of the node; "++" operator on
     * backward iterators follows the PREVIOUS pointer of the node.
     *
     * PRECONDTION: m_node is non-NULL.
     */
    Iterator& operator++();


    /**
     * Decrement an iterator; i.e., go to the "previous node" according to
     * the value of m_direction. I.e.,  "--" operator on forward
     * iterators follows the PREVIOUS pointer of the node; "--" operator on
     * backward iterators follows the NEXT pointer of the node.
     *
     * PRECONDTION: m_node is non-NULL.
     */
    Iterator& operator--();

    /**
     * Answer the question: Does "this" NOT point to the same node as "b"?
     */
    bool operator!=(Iterator const& b) const;

    /**
     * Overridden dereference operator* below allows to access item value
     * contained in this iterator's node.
     *
     * HINT: "const'ness" of this function indicates that none of "this"'s
     * members are changed while the function is running. It does not mean
     * that the returned Item's reference is "const", which WOULD be a
     * problem if we want to change item's value as in expression like:
     *
     *     (*myItr) = 3; // Assuming MyItr is an iterator object.
     *
     * We DON'T have this problem because the returned Item& is NOT const.
     * Expressions such as this are a valid, useful way of changing list
     * item values.
     *
     * PRECONDTION: m_node is non-NULL.
     */
    Item& operator*() const;

    /**
     * Delete/remove an item from the position correpsonding to the
     * iterator) inside the list and returns the item value; the iterator
     * should point to the "++ position" in the list according to the
     * value of m_direction. I.e., forward iterators should
     * point to the NEXT node after the deleted node; backward iterators
     * should point to the PREVIOUS node prior to the deleted node. Note
     * that the node in the "++ position" may be NULL.
     *
     * HINT 1: You can implement this really easily by exploiting one of
     * DLinkedOrderedList's removal methods...
     *
     * HINT 2: When following HINT 1, let DLinkedOrderedList's removal method
     * do the "++"-ing; make sure you don't increment twice by mistake!
     */
    Item kill();

    /**
     * Make DLinkedOrderedList a friend. This gives it access protected and
     * private members.
     *
     * HINT 3: Access to m_node greatly simplifies the implementation of
     * DLinkedOrderedList's "Item remove(Iterator& itr)" (see below).
     */
    friend class DLinkedOrderedList;
};

/**
 * Construct an empty list.
 */
DLinkedOrderedList();

/**
 * Make a copy of a list.
 */
DLinkedOrderedList(DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order> const& copy);

/**
 * Destruct a list. Delete all dynamically allocated nodes.
 */
~DLinkedOrderedList();

/**
 * Return the current list size. O(1).
 */
unsigned int size() const;

/**
 * Answer: Is the list empty? O(1).
 */
bool isEmpty() const;

/**
 * Get an iterator to the "beginning" or "off the ending" of this list.
 * Default to a forward iterator. Note that the "beginning" of the list for
 * a backward iterator is the tail of the list. Both are O(1).
 */
Iterator begin(Direction direction = FORWARD);
Iterator end(Direction direction = FORWARD);

/**
 * Insert an item into the correct location in the list according to the
 * ordering defined by our templated Order class. If Order::compare(a, b) is
 * true, then a must come before b in an ordered list. Return a forward
 * iterator pointing to the inserted value. Ordering of duplicate items
 * values does not matter, but each duplicate value should be included
 * exactly in the list. E.g.,
 *
 *     Inserting 2 into list: 1 <--> 2 <--> 3
 *     results in: 1 <--> 2 <--> 2 <--> 3
 *     It doesn't matter which "2 node" is the inserted node.
 *
 * This method should be O(n).
 */
Iterator insert(Item item);

/**
 * Remove a single "item"-valued item from the list and return true.
 * If no such item is found, return false. O(n).
 */
bool remove(Item item);

/**
 * Remove the specific node that "itr" refers to, and return the node's
 * value. "itr" should be adjusted to refer to the item in the "++ position"
 * with respect to the removed node (see comment under Iterator's "kill"
 * method for a detailed description). Note that this may be NULL! O(1).
 *
 * PRECONDITION: Iterator should be pointing at a valid position in the
 * list.
 */
Item remove(Iterator& itr);

/**
 * Remove all "item"-valued items from the list and return a count of the
 * number of such items found and removed. O(n).
 */
unsigned int removeAll(Item item);

private:
    /**
     * Standard list data structure members: head of the list, tail of the list,
     * size of the list.
     */
    Node* m_head;
    Node* m_tail;
    unsigned int m_size;
};


/**
 * CREATE THE THREE FILES #include'd BELOW AND INSERT YOUR CODE THERE!
 * To make debugging easier, include these files in your Visual Studio project.
 */
#include "DLinkedOrderedList.template.h"
#include "Node.template.h"
#include "Iterator.template.h"
```

Comment: Have you remembered [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)?

Answer (score 3):

The class template has already been defined in the "main" header `"DLinkedOrderedList.h"`, so don't define it again in the "template" header. Just define the member functions, e.g.

```
template <class Item, class Order>
DLinkedOrderedList::DLinkedOrderedList() : 
    m_head(NULL), m_tail(NULL), m_size(0)
{}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I tried defining the following member function, but apparently there are syntax errors: 
    template <class Item, class Order>
    Iterator& DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::Iterator::operator++(){}

Comment: @user3007481: You'll need to qualify the return type, `DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::Iterator`, since the return type isn't in class scope. (Parameters are, but leading return types aren't).

Comment: @user3007481: Or in C++11, you could use a trailing return type, which would be in class scope: `auto DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::Iterator::operator++() -> Iterator&`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. When I use the trailing return type, it works perfectly: 
     auto DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::Iterator::operator++()->Iterator&{}

Our prof hasn't taught us about trailing return types yet, so I assume he wants the standard member definition style. But when I use: 

     DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::Iterator& DLinkedOrderedList<Item, Order>::Iterator::operator++(){}

Answer (score 2):

Every header file should have a *header guard*:

```
#ifndef THIS_HEADER_H // Use a unique identifier for every file.
#define THIS_HEADER_H

// All contents of the header. Nothing goes before #ifndef or after #endif.

#endif
```

The lack of such a thing will cause a header included from different files to be processed twice, leading to literally all kinds of duplicate definition errors.

The example `DLinkedOrderedList.h` uses a nonstandard facility to solve the same issue, `#pragma once`, but this is not a generally accepted practice.

Furthermore, headers should all go at the top of a file, never at the bottom as your professor did. The canonical way to write a header (or any kind of program) is to state prerequisites, then implement additional functionality. There is no reason to diverge from the pattern here. You should be including `DLinkedOrderedList.h`, not the other way around. (In this case it is beyond your control, but just FYI.)

Comment: In this case, the problem is that the class really is defined twice, in two separate places, and include guards won't help with that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You're right; this issue threw me for a loop as for finding the actual problem though, and it's serious enough that I'll just leave this answer here.

Comment: They aren't real headers that are included at the bottom of the other header. They're template implementation files. Used by people who can't accept that's it's not possible to separate the template interface and implementation. So the implementation is put in a separate file and then included in the imterface file. As if that made any difference. Obviously it's required to include these template implementation files after the template interface file.

Comment: @john Template interface and implementation can be separated, but it doesn't require a "footer" file. The interface should be a separate header included from the implementation-header.

Comment: Well that would work, but then you are required to include the implementation file when the template is being used. So there's no separation in that case either.

Comment: @john There is a separation that works as long as you don't require instantiation. This is embodied in for example the standard `<iosfwd>` header. You can also use `extern template` declarations to forgo definitions of given specializations.